# HTML Using DIV vs. Table

Tags: html

What I like to do is to use a DIV's vs. Table.

I like to show an image and to the right of that image show text. The text should be aligned to the top edge of the image. There should be some spacing between the text the image.

I have the following code but seems like the image comes and then the text comes below it:

```
     <div style="float:left">
        <img src="../../images/img1.png" alt="Description" width="32" height="32"></a></p>
     </div>  

     <div style="clear:left"></div>

     <div style="float:left">    
         %#Eval("title")  
     </div>

     <div style="clear:left"></div>
```

Comment: Where does a table come in?

Comment: I am not using the table. I am trying to do it with just DIV

Comment: Probably be a lot more clear if you just removed the word `table` from your question.

Comment: If you are trying to simulate a `table` element with CSS, as it seems, you should a) tag the question primarily with “CSS” and b) show the working HTML code that you wish to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [float/overflow trick](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-clearing-floats-with-overflow):

```
<div class="imgCont">
    <img src="../../images/img1.png" alt="Description" width="32" height="32">
</div>
<div class="text">    
    %#Eval("title")  
</div>
```

I used classes instead of inline styling:

```
.imgCont{float:left; margin-right:10px;}
.text{overflow:hidden;}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/C2Yz7/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the first

```
<div style="clear:left"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <img src="../../images/img1.png" alt="Description" width="32" height="32"></a></p>
     <div>image</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#wrapper img, #wrapper div { float: left; }
#wrapper div { margin-left: 100px; } /* the size of your img + the space wanted */
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have this 2 divs:

```
<div style="clear:left"></div>
```

They just prevent your text div and your image div to be on the same row. Css property "clear" make your container to NEVER have another container floating, here on his left.

```
 <div style="float:left">
    <img src="../../images/img1.png" alt="Description" width="32" height="32"></a></p>
 </div>  

 <div style="float:left">    
     %#Eval("title")  
 </div>
```

It would be enough

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer!

Obviously use `div`. Here is a simple example!

You can first create a parent `div` then inside that parent div, you can create 2 divs like

```
<div>
  <div class="float-left"><img src="~/link_to_file.png" alt="photo" /></div>
  <div class="float-right">The text that would flow at the right side..</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for that.

1. You will be displaying them inline! I mean one div on left other on right!
2. You will be displaying the text on the top corner! Which means no `margin-top` for the text div.

Here is the CSS code:

```
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
.float-left, .float-right {
  display: inline; // use inline-block if you want to add padding or margins..
}
```

This way, the div with the image will align to the left and the other div will be placed to the right side! And they both will be in a line. As you want them to be.

Good luck, cheers! :)